# QGIS: Selecting active layer to be processed in Python script exported by Graphic Modeller

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I created a model and I would like to have it as a python script.

[image: this is what i see when i run my model]

This is what I see when I run my model and I can select a layer from this window. I don't necessarily need to select a layer, it can just process the active layer.

When I export this model as python code this is the corresponding part that select `myLayer` parameter.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class myModel(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('addlayer', 'myLayer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Result', 'Result', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
```

Is it possible to edit this code in order to make it target the active layer to process the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add `from qgis.utils import iface` line to import section.
- Remove `self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('addlayer', 'myLayer', ...)` line.
- And change all `parameters['addlayer']` into `iface.activeLayer()`.